# office 365 sharepoint wiki page library not available

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site, wiki, wiki-pages

I am pretty new to Office 365, but I have a business premium licence which includes also Sharepoint.

I created a new site, based on a topic communication template, where I would like to add a new page as Wiki Page Library, where I can put documents and knowledge based related to that site.

However I do not know how? It should be possible to add it as a new app according the following article from Microsoft support:
[Create and edit a wiki](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/create-and-edit-a-wiki-dc64f9c2-d1a2-44b5-ac59-b9d535551a32)

But my issue is that I do not see any Wiki Page Library when clicking on Add an app. And I do not think it is a permission issue as I am a global administrator of Office 365.

I've spent hours on Google trying to find solution, looking into different options in admin section of Office 365 and Sharepoint, but I am not able to find Wiki Page Library...

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears Microsoft has limited the Communications site to list and libraries that are supported in the "Modern UI" format. Wikis are not there (yet?).

If you want to do something that may not be officially supported, but seems to work just fine, edit your URL to go directly to the Wiki creation page.

```
https://yourDomain.sharepoint.com/sites/yourCommunicationSite/_layouts/15/new.aspx?FeatureId={00bfea71-c796-4402-9f2f-0eb9a6e71b18}&ListTemplate=119&
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need to activate "Wiki Page Home Page" feature from "Manage Site Features".

Navigate to Communication site->Site settings->Manage site features->activate "Wiki Page Home Page" feature:

[image]

Comment: and then when adding it, click "...check for them in the classic experience."